# Execute both PHP and JSP in the same document?

Tags: php, xml, jsp, tomcat

I have run into a specific circumstance where I need to be able to execute both php and jsp when they are in the same document. I have a tomcat server setup, with the java bridge [from here](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/doc/tomcat6.php) configured correctly. On their own, a .php document runs properly, and a .jsp document runs properly, but when combined, I get one or the other.

I have tried adding the .jsp extension to the php javabridge servlet mapping:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PhpCGIServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

but that results in only executing the php in a .jsp file. I have tried adding .php to the jsp servlet mapping

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.php</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

but that results in only executing the php in a .jsp file. Is there a way to have both php and jsp in the same file, and have it run both? Below is a sample of my code. Please don't suggest changing the code, because this is only a sample, and because what I am trying to test needs both of these to work in the same document. I would be willing to accept an answer of "This is not possible", but not before exhausting all other options.

```
<?php
$value = 'this_is_the_cookie';
setcookie("TestCookie", $value);
?><%@ page language="java" contentType="text/xml" import="javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder, javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory, org.w3c.dom.Document,org.w3c.dom.Element,org.w3c.dom.Node,org.w3c.dom.NodeList,java.io.*,java.util.*,org.voicexml.conformance.testharness.*" %><?php echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";?>
<callxml version="3.0"> 

<assign var="startTime" expr="time()"/>
<%!
    public String setDefault(String foo, String defValue)
    {
        if(foo == null)
        {
            return defValue;
        }
        else
        return foo;
    }

    String defValue = "0000";
    String testCaseID = request.getParameter("testcaseid");
    testCaseID = setDefault(testCaseID, defValue);
%>
<assign var="session.testCaseID"  value="<%=testCaseID%>"/>
<do label="B1">

    <prompt>
      CallXML Parent application.
    </prompt>

    <goto value="https://127.0.0.1:8888/MAMP/CallXML1.php"/>

</do>
</callxml>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

What about a filter in Java and then the normal jsp? or vice versa.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, can you give an example or more detail?

Comment: This link will give you all the details: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html

But basically, for your case: You could write in filter in java that would respond to whatever url you point the filter to. After that finishes, the php code will be executed.

Comment: I don't think that will work for me, because it wont allow me to assign the output of the jsp to a variable in the xml like this: `<assign var="session.testCaseID"  value="<%=testCaseID%>"/>`

Comment: Yes you can. After php finishes processing, you parse the output and replace "<%=testCaseID%>" with the value of that variable. It's horrible, but it will work.

Comment: I guess Im not following without some sort of example then, and I cant seem to find one that does that.

Comment: Fine. But I will take sometime. I need to download tomcat, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the PHP into your existing Web Application, you need to add the code directly to your `WEB-INF/web.xml` config file and the required library (`JavaBridge.jar, php-servlet.jar`) into your WEB-INF/lib folder. Check if you have a `php` installed and then add the following java arguments `-Dphp.java.bridge.php_exec=<location_of_php_bin>/php` to `catalina.sh or catalina.bat`

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>php.java.servlet.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>PhpJavaServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>php.java.servlet.PhpJavaServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>PhpCGIServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>prefer_system_php_exec</param-name>
        <param-value>On</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>php_include_java</param-name>
        <param-value>Off</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PhpJavaServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.phpjavabridge</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PhpCGIServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.php</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I did that, and like the original question says, this adds the ability to run a php file to tomcat, but does not add the ability to run both php and jsp at the same time, from the same document.

Comment: Yes, I have php installed. Like I said, when I add a php file to the app, the php executes perfectly fine. The running of php code is not the problem. The server is not running both php and jsp from the same document.

Comment: The solution that I can think off is to just separate the JSP code and then try including it from your PHP like `<?include('http://my_web_url/myjava.jsp');` I know you don't want to do this but that's the solution that I can think of for now.

Comment: If I did an include, how would I grab the parameters from the url? If the jsp isn't directly being started from the url, would doing `String testCaseID = request.getParameter("testcaseid");` still work?

Comment: basically after you've done updating the testCaseID, just put it back to the session and from your PHP, you may try to accessing it like using session command (`i.e. $_REQUEST['testcaseid']`)

Comment: I tried doing an include of the jsp in a separate document, and then doing a $_REQUEST for the variables I need, and they are coming through blank. Is there an example somewhere of how to do this you can point me to?

Answer (score 0):

Try including the JSP to PHP. It's like a normal include.